# How to grep columns and their ajoining rows of text from a .csv file then print in a specific pattern for zenity?

Tags: bash, csv

I asked this question once before but it was closed because it wasn't clear enough. I tried to edit it, but this website would not allow it. If the information below is still not clear enough,  please do not close and give me the chance to fix it.
I have a .csv file that contains a lot of text. I want a bash script that will allow me to input a keyword, then print all columns/rows related to keyword in a zenity text box.

My code e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="filename.csv"
ans=$(zenity --entry --title="Keyword?" --timeout=10);

function () {
while IFS= read -r i; do echo "${i%?}"; done < "$path"|grep "$ans*"
}

function | zenity --list --title="Results" --text=function --multiple --separator=" " \
--column="tile-of-col1" --column="title-of-col2"  --column="title-of-col3" --width 800 --height 200; exit;
```

What I expect:

```
title-of-col1               title-of-col2                title-of-col3
keyword info                info on same row             info on same row
```

What I get

```
title-of-col1                     title-of-col2                     title-of-col3
keyword,next column,next column   keyword,next column,next column
```

Only the first column contains the keyword. I do have multiple instances where the keyword appears throughout the .csv but only in the first column

The question is, how can I get the text to print in a column/row format?
The code above is an example. The actual code does not use generic terms like function, but does contain sensitive information that I do not wish to share.
This is not a zenity issue. Even if I

`cat filename.csv|grep keyword`

the results are still

`column-with-keyword,next-column-in-row-containing-keyword,next-column-in-row-containing-keyword`

Basically, if my keyword is help*, all columns containing any variation of help would then be printed and joined by their row

```
help-me,go to help.com,some more info
help me please,absolutely not,go back to using pen and paper
```

I would like for it to look like in a zenity window

```
help-me            go to help.web     some more info
help me please     absolutely not     just use pen and paper
```

(those above statements are being said in a joking manner and not inteded to be taken serious)

Comment: Start by analyzing your script using https://www.shellcheck.net/. Then check your regexs here https://regexr.com/

Comment: Although shellcheck.net offered some great suggestions, the output results are still the same. Didn't see anything wrong with regexs of the actual code. Again, the actual code contains sensitve infromation so I posted generic code for example.

Comment: Kudo's for posting a better Q! Go one step better and give us a small set of sample data and the expected output so we can test with it.  AND (sorry) it still seems overly complicated. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/info/bash and find the section titled "How to turn a bad script into a good question". The sample data can be "self-labeling", yes? R1C1, R1C2, R1C3 ; R2C1, R2C2, R2,C3; R3C1 ...... Get your filter to work on the command line then add in zenity at the end. Good luck!

Comment: Also People recommend to use shellcheck because they "see" the syntax hiccups and wonder if that is the cause of the problem. If you present a syntactically clean script, that eliminates a whole class of problem that has to be analyzed.

Comment: ok, I have posted what I get when I run the code and what I expect or would like to get. MY SCRIPT WORKS! This isn't a matter of something being broken. This is a question of getting the output/results of my script in a particualr format. I'm grepping a .csv file and the output separates the rows with a comma. I actuatlly want the output in column and row format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your question.

If you have this CSV

```
a,b,c
help me please,absolutely not,go back to using pen and paper
lorem ipsum, sit lorem, arundary
help-me,go to help.com,some more info
```

you could use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) to grep all records that contains `help` in every field, and create a pretty printed output in this way:

```
mlr --c2p grep 'help' input.csv
```

The output will be

```
a              b              c
help me please absolutely not go back to using pen and paper
help-me        go to help.com some more info
```

If you do not want the header in the output, you can change the command in this way

```
mlr --c2p --headerless-csv-output grep 'help' input.csv
```

Comment: Miller gives me the output exactly how I want it. I'm still not sure how nobody understands me. But thanks a bunch.

Comment: But in the end, luckily I understood you @Thomas.R